# Pandas Find rows within 24 hours of Series of dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of time series data and I also have a Series of timestamp objects at 2pm for about 80 days. My time series data is for the 5 days surrounding each of the days in my Series between 9:30am and 4pm. I need to get a truth Series for whether a row is within the 24 hour period preceeding the timestamps in the Series.

Here is what I have so far:

```
td = datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
df['fomc'] = df['time'].transform(lambda x: (x > dates_time + td).any() and (x < dates_time).any())
```

I realize that this is incorrect, but is there a way within Pandas to accomplish this?

Here is an example of a couple rows

```
time                | prc
0   1994-09-26 13:38:49  46.00
1   1994-09-26 13:57:15  46.04
2   1994-09-26 14:05:34  46.02
3   1994-09-26 14:07:18  46.13
```

Then I have a Series that looks like this:

```
0   1994-09-27
1   1994-11-15
2   1994-12-20
```

So it should the following Series:

```
0   False
1   False
2   True
3   True
```

Since the last two entries of the DataFrame are inside the 24 hour period preceeding the first entry in the Series.

edit: Sample input/output, corrections.

Comment: Can you please show a small example input and output? I _think_ I know what you're asking but there's no point working on the problem if I'm wrong in my understanding

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Why is the timestamp separated? Why do you need the timestamp if you've minute bars, just start as 9.30 and end at 16.

Comment: @roganjosh Just uploaded an example, is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @PedroLobito It's not quite minute bars, the way I stated that was misleading. What I am looking for is if the date is today -- 29-11-2018 -- I would want everything from after 2pm yesterday until today at 2pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be O(m*n) solution , but it should be fast than pandas method , using `numpy` broadcast

```
df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time)
v=df.time.values
v1=(v-s.values[:,None])/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')

np.any((v1>-24)&(v1<0),0)
Out[424]: array([False, False,  True,  True])
```

Comment: Thank for this answer, I just don't understand what is the `s` in line 3 ? Did a step has been removed ?